# Why is the word "Event" highlighted in blue in ssms?

Tags: sql-server

I don't see it as a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx), so why does ssms highlight in blue?
I can

```
create table event
```

but it's disconcerting if it's highlighted in blue.

Comment: I couldn't stand the sight of [event] everywhere in my code. I decided to use evnt.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is related with ([`CREATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677289.aspx), [`ALTER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630368.aspx), [`DROP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630257.aspx)) `EVENT SESSION`. You can read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630284.aspx) about this stuff (this works since SQL Server 2008).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has [EVENT NOTIFICATION](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182602(v=sql.105).aspx)s, which are a special kind of database object that sends information about server and database events to a [Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx) service.  It's kind of like an asynchronous trigger.

Here's a [blog post](http://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2015/05/who-backed-up-my-database.html) that shows how to use an EVENT NOTIFICATION to alert when a database has been backed up or restored.

Also, [Colleen Morrow](http://colleenmorrow.com/) has many great articles about SERVICE BROKER on her blog.